# How to select variables for plotting using text box input?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to be able to use a text box input to select which variables will be plotted by the pairs.panels() method (similarly to how people define what pages to be printed by a printer). For example I would like to be able to enter in the box the following:
1,3:5 in order to plot the pair correlations of variables 1,3,4 and 5.

Thank you!

```r
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3),
                 v2 = rnorm(3),
                 v3 = rnorm(3),
                 v4 = rnorm(3),
                 v5 = rnorm(3),
                 v6 = rnorm(3))

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            textInput("subset", label = "Variables subset:")
        ),

        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("plot"),
           verbatimTextOutput("text")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # This is to test what the string from the text box looks like
    output$text <- renderPrint({
        col_sel <- input$subset
        col_sel <- paste("c(", input$subset, ")", sep = "")
        print(col_sel)
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        col_sel <- paste("c(", input$subset, ")", sep = "")
        pairs.panels(df[,col_se],                                      # THIS DOES NOT WORK
                     method = "pearson",
                     hist.col = "#FCF928",
                     density = TRUE
        )

    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some none-standard evaluation; I use `rlange` from the tidyverse. First, I convert the string to an expression (unevaluated code) with `parse_expr`. Then I evaluate this code with `eval_bare` so that the actual numbers needed for indexing are calculated:

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3),
                 v2 = rnorm(3),
                 v3 = rnorm(3),
                 v4 = rnorm(3),
                 v5 = rnorm(3),
                 v6 = rnorm(3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("subset", label = "Variables subset:")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      verbatimTextOutput("text")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # This is to test what the string from the text box looks like
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    col_sel <- input$subset
    col_sel <- paste("c(", input$subset, ")", sep = "")
    print(col_sel)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    col_sel <- paste("c(", input$subset, ")", sep = "")
    pairs.panels(df[,rlang::eval_bare(rlang::parse_expr(col_sel))],                                      
                 method = "pearson",
                 hist.col = "#FCF928",
                 density = TRUE
    )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```